# Change "LiveUSB" default boot options

Tags: boot, grub2, live-usb

A friend of mine wants to use livecd to use ubuntu (Maverick). He is currently setting acpi=off every time manually. How can I set the default option to acpi=off. Btw he didnt install ubuntu in his machine. He is directly booting from live cd.

It is a live usb so I can edit anything.

Comment: Obviously you cannot modify anything on a CD, it is read-only.
Do you mean modifying the iso file and burning the modified iso to disk?

Comment: Sorry it is a live usb. I've updated the post

Answer (score 4):

I think you can edit the `/boot/grub/loopback.cfg` file (when you made the stick with usb-creator) or the `/syslinux.cfg` file (when you used unetbootin) on the USB stick to include this.

Comment: Yes, but does Unetbootin update it?

Answer (score 2):

I'd try this way (note that I'm making some assumptions so I'm not sure that would work):

1. Boot in a regular OS (not the one on the USB you want to tweak).
2. Mount the USB drive and open USB_drive/syslinux/txt.cfg with a text editor.
3. Locate the image you usually boot to, it should be something like:

   ```
   label live
   menu label ^Try Ubuntu without installing
   kernel /casper/vmlinuz
   append noprompt cdrom-detect/try-usb=true persistent file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --
   ```
4. The relevant part is the append line, add `acpi=off` to it before `--`, I'd put it in between `initrd=...` and `quiet`.
5. Save your edits.
6. umount your USB drive.
7. Boot your LiveUSB and keep your fingers crossed.
8. (optional) Come back here to insult me if this procedure doesn't work or praise me if everything was fine. :P
9. Report any advice you have or any progress you made.

Useful resources:

- [Syslinux wiki](http://www.syslinux.org/wiki/index.php/SYSLINUX)