# Unable to use USB device that was used to create UBUNTU bootable

Tags: live-usb, usb-drive

I created a Ubuntu bootable USB stick with San Disk cruzer 8GB. Now, I am not able to re-format the flash drive.

I searched on-line for solution but am not able to understand since, I am new to Ubuntu.

I have attached a screen shot of the error so that you can understand and help me sort this issue.

[image]

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: How did you format UFD,  what format did you use and where did you format it?

Comment: Probably hybrid DVD/flash & you need to erase start of drive, see this: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb#Re-use_the_pendrive and this: https://askubuntu.com/questions/922692/how-to-edit-a-bootable-usb-stick?noredirect=1#comment1457639_922692

Comment: The usual way to format USB in a Ubuntu installed system.

Comment: Actually, I have two flash drive and both are screwed.

Answer (score 1):

Some boot drive makers install Ubuntu as an ISO 9660 partition.

Gparted is not very good at ISO 9660 partitions, however you might try creating a new partition table on the USB using gparted. You might have to hit ignore a few times then cancel.If there is a problem you can get the ISO partition unmounted using Disks.

You can also restore the drive using **mkusb's** "restore to a standard storage device" function, this method always works for me.

I have had multi partition flash drives brick when formatting on Windows.

Comment: +1. @akurn940mx, See also these links, [mkusb](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb) and [mkusb/wipe](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/mkusb/wipe)

Answer (score 0):

I always have that problem after any Linux installation.

1. Grab windows machine from a neighbor. Plug the USB in and
2. Start -> Disk management
3. Look for the USB drive(Touch only the Pendrive at the Disk mgmt),
4. Click on the partition block and delete all the partition tables created by the boot process
5. Right click on the final empty space and create an new partition, choose fat32 as file format. And format it.
   --- Voila ---

Comment: Let me try that, I will get back to you.